# Generating iTunes XML nodes in RSS feed using Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rss, itunes

**Q: How do I generate the XML nodes specific to iTunes using Ruby/Rails?**

Trying to generate iTunes XML feed, e.g. (based off [example](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/32-create-an-rss-feed-in-rails)):

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0" 
xml.rss(:version => "2.0") do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title "Your Blog Title"
    xml.description "A blog about software and chocolate"
    xml.link posts_url

    @posts.each do |post|
      xml.item do
        xml.title post.title
        xml.description "Temporary post description"
        xml.pubDate post.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.link post_url(post)
        xml.guid post_url(post)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which happily generates something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Your Blog Title</title>
    <description>A blog about software and chocolate</description>
    <link>https://pubweb-thedanielmay.c9.io/sermons</link>
    <item>
       ... omitted ...
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

But looks like I need to generate iTunes-specific XML nodes (as per [Working With iTunes](https://www.apple.com/au/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#rss), e.g.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0"> <-- *
  <channel>
    <title>Your Blog Title </title>
    ... omitted ...
    <itunes:subtitle>A program about everything</itunes:subtitle> <-- *
... etc ...
```

**Not sure how I generate the iTunes-specific nodes as they have colons in them.**

Standard RSS nodes are like:

```
xml.item --> <item>
```

**How do I get to generating nodes like:**

- `<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">`
- `<itunes:author>`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, answers as per code via Ryan Bates' awesome Railscasts [RSS sample](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/views/episodes/index.rss.builder)

```
xml.rss "xmlns:itunes" => "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd", :version => "2.0"
```

and

```
xml.itunes :author, author
```